# Move mode in document picker extension

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, document-provider

I am trying to create a file with Word mobile app and save it in my application, for which i have implemented document picker extension for my application with ‘move’ mode enabled. So when i create a file with Word app and try to save it, i could see my app’s name in the document picker and when tapping that, my extension code gets executed where i am able to get the file url of the newly created file using ‘originalURL' property of UIDocumentPickerExtensionViewController. But when I try getting the size of the file from that URL, it always returns zero.
So am i missing anything obvious here?
Is that the correct way to get the file’s path with ‘originalURL’?
Apple doc defines the ‘originalURL’ as a read-only property that contains the original file’s URL when in export or move mode. Otherwise it contains nil.’

Comment: Hi @XiOS, any update on this? I am also facing the same problem. Saw this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4755, but no solution. Thanks.